# freeing a pStruct from a different function

Tags: c, struct, queue, malloc, free

I'm currently learning queues in class and I've been having trouble figuring out where to free this struct.

```
void addNewProcessToSchedule( schedule *ps, char *processName, int stepsUntilComplete, priority p ) {
    /* TODO: complete this function.
    The function "initializeProcessData" in processSimulator.c will be useful in completing this. */
    process *new=malloc(sizeof(process));
    new->processName=processName;
    new->stepsUntilComplete=stepsUntilComplete;
    new->prevTimeSteps=0;
    new->prio=p;
    new->processData=initializeProcessData(processName);
    if(new->prio==0)
        enqueue(ps->foregroundQ, new);
    else{
        enqueue(ps->backgroundQ, new);
    }
}
```

This function results in `new` leaving behind some unfreed bytes. I can't free it in the function as the queue node will be NULL'd. This is the struct for `process`

```
typedef struct process
{
    char* processName;
    int stepsUntilComplete;
    int prevTimeSteps;
    processData* processData;
    priority prio;
}  process;
```

Here is the call from main:

```
for( i=0; i<5; i++){
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(testData[i])+1);
    strcpy( temp, testData[i] );
    addNewProcessToSchedule( ps, temp, getRuntime(temp), getPriority(temp) );
}
```

I tried using a static pointer just to point at `new` but that caused more problems than it solved.
Static pointers don't work and neither does calling in the function. I'm at a loss.

Comment: "This function results in new leaving behind some unfreed bytes." What do you mean? This function allocates and initializes data. Freeing must be done somewhere else, e.g. where the node is remove from the queue. Or at another function that is called to free up the data. "I can't free it in the function as the queue node will be NULL'd." Where is this happening?

Comment: The code you show is far away from being a complete sample that would allow analyzing what you are doing.